# .htaccess Allow POST method for ONLY cetain IP ranges

Tags: .htaccess

I want a certain range of ips (Canada Country Block IPS) to only be able to use the POST method in my login page (http://www.mysite.com/index.php?m=account_login) and my registration page
(http://www.mysite.com/index.php?m=account_register)
However i want all ips to have access to my main site http://www.mysite.com/index.php and be able to use the POST method there such as our contact page
(http://www.mysite.com/index.php?m=contactus)

Thank you.

```
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
# Country: CANADA
# ISO Code: CA
# Total Networks: 6,365
# Total Subnets:  79,978,496
allow from 23.16.0.0/16
allow from 23.17.0.0/16
allow from 24.36.0.0/16
allow from 24.37.0.0/16
...
allow from 192.197.216.0/24
allow from 216.254.192.0/19
#
deny from all
</Limit>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight way to implement this but I did this myself with little trick:-D
`Limit`  checks ONLY request method, so there is no way to check file or URL. solution for this is to use `FilesMatch`  directive. BUT here, we have a problem,like I had: QUERY STRING :-(.
Solution for this one is to use `RewriteRule`

RewriteRule  login.html     index.php?m=account_login   [L,QSA]
RewriteRule  register.html  index.php?m=account_register [L,QSA]

Now, we have everything we want:

```
<FilesMatch "(login|register)\.html$"> 
     <Limit  GET POST>
        order deny,allow
        # Country: CANADA
        # ISO Code: CA
        # Total Networks: 6,365
        # Total Subnets:  79,978,496
          allow from 23.16.0.0/16
          allow from 23.17.0.0/16
          allow from 24.36.0.0/16
          allow from 24.37.0.0/16
          allow from 192.197.216.0/24
          allow from 216.254.192.0/19

          deny from all
     </Limit> 
</FilesMatch>

RewriteRule  (register|login)\.html     index.php?m=account_$1&allow=yes  [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     m=account_(register|login)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    !allow=yes
RewriteRule index\.php   - [F,L]
```

I prefer to create new file for logging in or registering to avoid `RewriteRule`s.